# how to change the maximum number of connection to Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle

How do I change the maximum number of connection to Oracle database at start? 
I use :

```
ALter system set sessions=500 scope=spfile;
```

However, after restart the database, use show parameter sessions still give value 772 for sessions

Khue.

Comment: Khue - how do you extract the sessions value?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742794/ora-12516-tnslistener-could-not-find-available-handler

Answer (score 3):

are you also changing PROCESSES parameter afterwards?  [sessions is a derived parameter.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams001.htm#i556848)

Try changing sessions last?

Comment: Hi Nick, 
Thanks for your help. I only changed the sessions param. And I get the output 'system altered' after that.

Comment: Hi Nick, I find the answer to this. I lowered down the processes parameter and then the sessions parameter is changed. I guess we can set sessions below a certain threshold regarding processes.

Comment: what version or oracle?

Comment: This answer sounds more like a comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change:

   echo "alter system set processes=1000 scope=spfile;" | sqlplus system/password@localhost:1521/orcl

   echo "alter system set sessions=1000 scope=spfile;" | sqlplus system/password@localhost:1521/orcl
2. **Restart DB**
3. Check:

   echo "SELECT value FROM v\$parameter WHERE name = 'processes';" | sqlplus system/password@localhost:1521/orcl

   echo "SELECT value FROM v\$parameter WHERE name = 'sessions';" | sqlplus system/password@localhost:1521/orcl